# I can't find anything about it.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

I translated this theory.And my english is not well.I need something  (proof,book etc) about this theory:
"There are n elements and permutation of these elements is n! .It is possible to arrange them in such a way that, each permutation consist of a transposition from the previous one."

Comment: What do yo call a transpose ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Given the apology for poor english, the OP *might* just mean "transposition". What do you think?

Comment: @ProfessorVector: in such situations, I prefer not to make any guess and wait for the OP to explain.

Comment: @Yves Daoust And if the OP fails to do so (remember poor english) you'll happily vote for close/delete, right? Well, that's the MSE we know and love...

Comment: @Yves Daoust thank you for your anwser.I mean transposition.

Comment: And I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that "transpose" means transposition and you are looking for a method of ordering the permutations of n elements so that each permutation is obtained by applying a transposition to the one before.

One method for doing this is [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the answer: the OP wants *all* $n!$ permutations in that chain, so you'd need an algorithm with a worst case complexity of $n!$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: what do you mean ? This algorithm does answer the question. And it has no "worst case".

Comment: @Yves Daoust Sorry, I stand corrected. Yes, it does answer the question. I'm mostly working in IT, now, and was thinking of a sorting algorithm, but it's enumeration in this case.